# QuickSort in Java not delivering sorted results

Tags: java, quicksort

I tried to implement the code for QuickSort using the algorithm which was mentioned on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm .

But, I am not able to get a sorted output. Rather, I am only getting the same array as the output.

Can anybody review it for me and tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
public class QuickSort {

private int[] arr;

private void quick_sort(int[] input, int lo, int hi){
    this.arr = input;
    if(lo<hi){
        int p = partition(arr, lo, hi);
        if(lo < p-1)
            quick_sort(arr, lo, p-1);
        if(hi > p+1)
            quick_sort(arr, p+1, hi);
    }
}

private int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi){
    int pivotIndex = hi;  //last element
    int pivotVal = arr[pivotIndex];
    int j = lo;

    for(int i = lo; i<hi; i++){
        if(arr[i] < pivotVal){
            swap(arr[j],arr[i]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr[j],pivotVal);
    return j;
}

private void swap(int l, int r){
    l = l+r;
    r = l-r;
    l = l-r;
}


private void printArray(){
    for(int i : arr)
        System.out.print(i+", ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    QuickSort q = new QuickSort();
    int[] input = {10, 5, 15, 3, 20, 30, 25, 19};
    q.quick_sort(input, 0, input.length-1);
    q.printArray();
}
};
```

Output:

```
10, 5, 15, 3, 20, 30, 25, 19,
```

Comment: Partial answer: your problem is your swap method.

Comment: Not a real answer, but this page has some really nice information and samples about quicksort: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swap method is incorrect. Java is always pass by value, and primitives can't be modified like that. Instead, pass in the array (the value of an array, as an `Object` instance, is its' reference) and the indexes to swap like

```
private void swap(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
    int t = arr[l];
    arr[l] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = t;
}
```

And then you can call it like

```
private int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    int pivotIndex = hi; // last element
    int j = lo;

    for (int i = lo; i < hi; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[pivotIndex]) {
            swap(arr, j, i);
            j++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr, j, pivotIndex);
    return j;
}
```

Output (with just those changes) is

```
3, 5, 10, 15, 19, 20, 25, 30,
```

Also, you could print the array like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Oh thank you, How could I have missed that. I'm only swapping the values but how is my array 'going to know about it'. Ahh, Thank you. Can't vote up because of low reputation. But this works fine.
Also, Another question. I have been using this method for swapping for a while, because it worked well. I read it in some blog or something - that this is a good way to swap things because you don;t require a third variable , should I not use it anymore?

Comment: It looks like a broken version of the [XOR Swap Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm), and I would suggest you don't use that in Java. Instead you should [**Write Dumb Code**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html). Also, even without reputation, as the asker you can [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).